# object property with a random number appended

Tags: object, testcomplete

I have a problem in testcomplete where I have an object with a property that has a text string and then a random number appended (i.e. help4) This number changes per object but in no logical way, i.e. it could be help4 or it could be help18.

I'm trying to have my test search for this object but need to know how to tell it to look for help plus the random number, any ideas?

I'm new to all this so explanations in as simplistic way possible would be most helpful.

The language is CS-Script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the variable part of the name with the wildcard character. For example:

```
parent.WinFormsObject("help*").ClickButton();
```

If you are using Name Mapping, you need to replace the variable part of the name with the wildcard character in the mapping criteria.